# Crosstabulation based on values in two columns

Tags: r, crosstab

I have a crosstabulation problem. My data has 9600 rows, and here is a simplified sample, where I have removed several parameters:

```
Year   Sex    Area
1938    F      2
1938    M      2
1939    M      2
1939    M      5
1955    F      4
1957    F      4
1955    M      4
1943    M      6
1988    F      1
1988    M      2
1987    M      2
1955    M      3
1984    M      4
1984    F      5
1966    M      6
1955    F      8
1984    F      9
1955    M      3
1981    M      6
1938    F      6
```

I am looking for a table that crosstabulates my data like this, and I need the tally of cases Area~Year, not the aggregated sum of the parameter values.

```
Year   Area=1  Area=2  Area=3  Area=3  Area=5  Area=6  Area=7  Area=8  Area=9
1938     7       0       1       9       2       8       1      14       4 
1939     4       4      12      66       3      42      87      24      54 
1940     9      33       1       1       6      22       1       5      15 
1941     12      2       8      77      11      23       4      14       6 
...
```

I know there are several ways to do this, and they're probably quite simple, but I can't find the right procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dcast function

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Year~Area, value.var = "Area", fun.aggregate = length)
```

Result:

```
   Year 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9
1  1938 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0
2  1939 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
3  1943 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
4  1955 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 0
5  1957 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
6  1966 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
7  1981 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
8  1984 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
9  1987 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
10 1988 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can rename the columns further.

```
ct <- dcast(df, Year~Area, value.var = "Area", fun.aggregate = length)
colnames(ct) <- c(colnames(ct[1]), paste0("Area=", colnames(ct[-1])))
ct
```

Result:

```
   Year Area=1 Area=2 Area=3 Area=4 Area=5 Area=6 Area=8 Area=9
1  1938      0      2      0      0      0      1      0      0
2  1939      0      1      0      0      1      0      0      0
3  1943      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
4  1955      0      0      2      2      0      0      1      0
5  1957      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
6  1966      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
7  1981      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0
8  1984      0      0      0      1      1      0      0      1
9  1987      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
10 1988      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: This procedure worked well for a while, but now I get this warning :                 Using 'mainarea' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
Warning message:
In dcast(catch, Year ~ mainarea) :
  The dcast generic in data.table has been passed a data.frame and will attempt to redirect to the reshape2::dcast; please note that reshape2 is deprecated, and this redirection is now deprecated as well. Please do this redirection yourself like reshape2::dcast(catch). In the next version, this warning will become an error.

Comment: Udated my answer. Use reshape2 package instead of data.table and call value.var and fun.aggregate as shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` :

```
table(df$Year, df$Area)


#       1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9
#  1938 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0
#  1939 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
#  1943 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#  1955 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 0
#  1957 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#  1966 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#  1981 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#  1984 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
#  1987 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  1988 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  count(Year, Area) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Area, values_from = n, 
              values_fill = list(n = 0), names_prefix = 'Area')
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1938L, 1938L, 1939L, 1939L, 1955L, 1957L, 
1955L, 1943L, 1988L, 1988L, 1987L, 1955L, 1984L, 1984L, 1966L, 
1955L, 1984L, 1955L, 1981L, 1938L), Sex = c("F", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", 
 "M", "M", "F"), Area = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 6L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: When using the 'table' command I don't get a matrix data frame, but only two columns, Year in the first and the areas in the other, first Area 1, then Area 2 etc.

Comment: @Dag That is strange as I am not able to reproduce that. I updated the post with the data that I am using and it gives me the same output as shown in my post. Can you check using that data if it works for you?

Comment: When I run the procedure the result is showing on up in the right format in the console. However, the resulting object is a df with a 3-column table of Var1, Var2, and Freq.

Comment: I am guessing that you are using `data.frame(table(df$Year, df$Area))`.  If you want to convert the above table to dataframe use `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df$Year, df$Area))`